# Discord.js embed doesn't show up

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I'm trying to make an embed message using discord.js, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'how to embed') {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('A slick little embed')
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!');
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In this code, you have to define the MessageEmbed. If you just used `const Discord = require('discord.js');`, it will throw a ReferenceError that MessageEmbed is not defined. try `new Discord.MessageEmbed()` or add `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');` at the top of your code. It will work.

PS: Well I also had that problem when I first started discord.js bot

Comment: then upvote please i can't write comments to questions yet. 40 reps️(???)

Answer (score 0):

Should be this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'how to embed') {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('A slick little embed')
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            .setDescription('Hello, this is a slick embed!');
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

You were missing `Discord.`MessageEmbed()

Answer (score 0):

Change MessageEmbed() to Discord.MessageEmbed()

And make sure you have const Discord = require(‘discord.js’)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to import or require the discord.js `const discord = require('discord.js');` 
then

```
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        //your embed settings
```

then you can send the embed.

Comment: try to give Lil more description in answer. it is nice to explain in details